# Can I use HINCRBY/INCR in Redis to guarantee an integer response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I'm using the [redis-objects](https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects) gem to implement some counters on rails models. Some of the counters are singular (so modeled like `counter foo` backed by a single redis value) but others could have some number of keys, modeled as `hash_key bar` and backed by a redis hash with `HINCRBY`.

So far so good, however the values returned from the hash are strings, not ints, because redis-objects doesn't know that the hash is a counter. I could just `.to_i` the results, but this could result in unpredictable behavior if a key was overwritten by a non-int value, for example.

Can I use `HINCRBY myhash field 0` to force redis to interpret the field value as an int64 and produce an Integer reply (`:1..`) with semantics compatible with normal increment? Will this cause a lock or other undesirable behavior related to using a "write" op as a read? Is there a better way to cast the read?